# Что делать если цикл не останавливается при достижении одной переменной в python?

Tags: python, циклы

Создал программку, всё работает, только цикл не останавливается при достижении цели.
Вот скрипт:

```
import random
PlySc = 0
ComSc = 0

print('Игра \"Камень, ножницы, бумага\". Нужно набрать 3 балла для выигрыша')

while(PlySc < 3 or (ComSc < 3)):
  Act = int(input('Выберите действие: 1 - камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага: '))

  CompAct = random.randint(1, 3)
  #print(CompAct)
  if(Act == 1 and(CompAct == 2)):
    print('Компьютер выбрал ножницы, вы выиграли')
    PlySc += 1
    print('Счёт: Вы -',PlySc, 'Компьютер -',ComSc)
    act = 0
  elif(Act == 1 and(CompAct == 3)):
    print('Компьютер выбрал бумагу, вы проиграли')
    ComSc += 1
    print('Счёт: Вы -',PlySc, 'Компьютер -',ComSc)
    act = 0
  elif(Act == 2 and(CompAct == 1)):
    print('Компьютер выбрал камень, вы проиграли')
    ComSc += 1
    print('Счёт: Вы -',PlySc, 'Компьютер -',ComSc)
    act = 0
  elif(Act == 2 and(CompAct == 3)):
    print('Компьютер выбрал бумагу, вы выиграли')
    PlySc += 1
    print('Счёт: Вы -',PlySc, 'Компьютер -',ComSc)
    act = 0
  elif(Act == 3 and(CompAct == 1)):
    print('Компьютер выбрал камень, вы выиграли')
    PlySc += 1
    print('Счёт: Вы -',PlySc, 'Компьютер -',ComSc)
    act = 0
  elif(Act == 3 and(CompAct == 2)):
    print('Компьютер выбрал ножницы, вы проиграли')
    ComSc += 1
    print('Счёт: Вы -',PlySc, 'Компьютер -',ComSc)
    act = 0
  elif(Act > 3):
    print('Выберите число от 1 - 3!')
    act = 0
  else:
    print('Ничья!')
    print('Счёт: Вы -',PlySc, 'Компьютер -',ComSc)
    act = 0
if(PlySc == 3):
  print('Вы победили!')
elif(ComSc == 3):
  print('Вы проиграли!')
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Использовать ключевое слово break. Оно дает инструкцию выйти из цикла while или for.

Comment: У вас ошибка в условии цикла: `while PlySc < 3 or ComSc < 3`, означает, что цикл будет продолжаться, пока _хотя бы одно_ число меньше 3; нужно `or` заменить на `and`, то есть, пока _оба_ числа меньше 3 : `while PlySc < 3 and ComSc < 3:`

Answer (score 2):

Основная ошибка в условии цикла:
`while PlySc < 3 or ComSc < 3:` означает, что цикл будет продолжаться, пока *хотя бы одно* число меньше 3.

Достаточно `or` заменить на `and`, то есть, пока *оба* числа меньше 3:
`while PlySc < 3 and ComSc < 3:`

---

Кроме того, данный код и его логику можно значительно упростить, избавившись от ненужных скобок и конъюнкций `and` в условных операторах и неиспользуемой переменной `act`:

- сразу после ввода числа пользователем следует проверить его корректность
- затем следует проверить совпадение ответов (ничейный результат)
- и только после этого можно сравнивать различные ответы

```py
import random

PlySc = 0
ComSc = 0

print('Игра \"Камень, ножницы, бумага\". Нужно набрать 3 балла для выигрыша')

while PlySc < 3 and ComSc < 3:
    Act = int(input('Выберите действие: 1 - камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага: '))

    CompAct = random.randint(1, 3)

    if Act not in [1, 2, 3]:
        print('Выберите целое число от 1 до 3!')
    elif Act == CompAct:
        print('Ничья!')
    else:
        if Act == 1:
            if CompAct == 2:
                print('Компьютер выбрал ножницы, вы выиграли')
                PlySc += 1
            else:
                print('Компьютер выбрал бумагу, вы проиграли')
                ComSc += 1
        elif Act == 2:
            if CompAct == 3:
                print('Компьютер выбрал бумагу, вы выиграли')
                PlySc += 1
            else:
                print('Компьютер выбрал камень, вы проиграли')
                ComSc += 1
        else:
            if CompAct == 1:
                print('Компьютер выбрал камень, вы выиграли')
                PlySc += 1
            else:
                print('Компьютер выбрал ножницы, вы проиграли')
                ComSc += 1
    print('Счёт: Вы -', PlySc, 'Компьютер -', ComSc)
if PlySc == 3:
    print('Вы победили!')
else:
    print('Вы проиграли!')
```

Answer (score 0):

потому что прежде чем у тебя закончится цикл совершаются еще действие
сделай такое действие

```
if(Act == 1 and CompAct == 2):
    if  PlySc < 3 or ComSc < 3:
       pass
    else:
    print('Компьютер выбрал ножницы, вы выиграли')
    PlySc += 1
    print('Счёт: Вы -',PlySc, 'Компьютер -',ComSc)
    act = 0
```